# Anaconda virtual environment not recognizing Python

Tags: python, anaconda

Whenever I run the commands `which conda`, `which pip`, and `which python` in the `base` environment, it works fine but whenever I activate the virtual environment using the `conda activate` command it doesn't recognize those and says `no conda/pip in ...`.

Does anybody have a solution to this? Is this simply a path problem and I need to set a separate path for the virtual environment? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the Python package `virtualenv`? That is not compatible with Conda envs. If you use Conda, you should use `conda create` to make envs, and not `virtualenv`.

Comment: Yes, I created the virtual environment via `conda create`. Still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Hmm, indeed that's strange. Could you please edit the question to include a full set of commands (and outputs) that you run as an example? E.g., from `conda create -n foo python`, `conda activate foo`, and then `which python`, etc.